# How to lookup EJB remoting from a EJB application into a java application?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi, remote-access, jboss-eap-6

I'm working on a tow projects , EJB project (where i have all my EJB Remote) and the other project is a simple java application with main method. but when i try to lookup  an EJB statless and remote via JNDI , it doesn't work.

Really i used many way but no good results.

this is the code and the consol error .

1) My Ejb project when i clean and install it , it gives me a jar file.
2) I use Jboss EAP6.
3) i have a **jndi.properties** insid of src/main/ressouces where i have this :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url = localhost:1099
```

**PersonalFactory.java** (EJB of the EJB project)

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import com.lazrak.common.logging.CommonLogger;
import com.lazrak.remotes.IPersonFactoryRemote;

@Remote(IPersonFactoryRemote.class)
@Stateless
public class PersonFactory implements  IPersonFactoryRemote

@Override
public void findMe() {
System.out.println("I'am inside of the method findMe");
}
```

**MyMainClass.java** (where i have the main method and it is in the second java project)

All import ...

```
public class MyMainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

System.out.println("Main start ");
    invokeStatelessBean();
}

private static void invokeStatelessBean(){

     Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
     props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
     props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");      
     props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");
     InitialContext context = null;

try {
        context = new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Faild to add properties to InitialContext"+e.getMessage());
    }

try {
    final IPersonFactoryRemote statelessRemoteCalculator = (IPersonFactoryRemote) context
                .lookup("ejb:"+moduleName+"/"+PersonFactory.class.getSimpleName();+"/"+IPersonFactoryRemote.class.getName());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("EJB Remot doesn't been fined\n"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

when i run my main application , it gives me that :

```
Main start
enter 2014-09-26 15:57:26,098 DEBUG org.jboss.logging - InitialContextFactory.java:64 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/remoting3/spi/ConnectionProviderFactory
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.<clinit>(InitialContextFactory.java:99)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.<clinit>(InitialContextFactory.java:99)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at RemoteEJBClient.invokeStatelessBean(RemoteEJBClient.java:42)
at RemoteEJBClient.main(RemoteEJBClient.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.jboss.remoting3.spi.ConnectionProviderFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 11 more
```

Comment: i tested this too but it doesn't work for me :

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

and of course the jar of EJB project is delployed on the jboss EAP6

Answer (score 0):

```
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");      
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");
```

Those properties are used for connecting to an older jboss version.. For eap 6, you have to use remoting instead of jnp.

Here´s a tutorial that will show you how to connect

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial